# Do Tripsta flights prices include checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bookings, pegasus-airlines

I'm trying to book a flight on Tripsta website, but it doesn't show in details if the payment includes checked luggage. The airline is "Pegasus airlines" and I am trying to book an economy class.

Also I am not willing to pay more than what Tripsta offering.

Comment: you cal also book directly through pegasus airlines : https://www.flypgs.com/en

Answer (score 5):

When, as @AliAwan suggests, you use the [Pegasus](https://book.flypgs.com/) site, it returns results with four pricing options, from lowest price to highest:

- Basic : only hand bag
- Essentials : 20kg baggage
- Advantage : seat selection, inflight food & drink, 20kg baggage
- Extras : change and refund seat selection, inflight food and drink, 20kg baggage

This suggests that, no, the lowest price does not include checked baggage. [Pegasus Hand Baggage](https://www.flypgs.com/en/useful-info/info-about-flights/general-rules#1329), in the General Rules, is described as

> baggage taken onto the plane by the passengers. One hand baggage
>   of 20 cm x 40 cm x 55 cm, with maximum weight of 8kg is allowed.

Comment: Stay with me @DavidRicherby

Comment: this answer is relevant to the question

Comment: @AliAwan That's because it was edited after I commented that it wasn't!

Comment: @ David Richerby i don't see any disagreement here